# Cypher - get all associated relationships for a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following setup:

A doctor can have multiple patients, and every patient can have multiple diagnosis.
I need to return for Doctor X, all his associated patients and their associated diagnosis.
How can I write a nested relationship query as follows?
I have the following query for now:

```
 MATCH
(p: Patient)-[:PATIENT_AT]->(d:Doctor),
(di:Diagnosis)-[:DIAGNOSIS_BY]->(d:Doctor),
(p:Patient)-[:HAS_DIAGNOSIS]->(di:Diagnosis)
WHERE
 d.id=1000000
 RETURN p,di
```

But this is returning me two separate queries. Can I get the same result in one query like:

```
   patient 1--> all diagnosis
   patient 2 --> all diagnosis
```

Or do I need two separate loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single query: probably something like this would do what you're looking for (untested, since I don't have your data, but... should be close):

```sql
MATCH (doc:Doctor {id=1000000})<-[:PATIENT_AT]-(pat:Patient)-[:HAS_DIAGNOSIS]->(diag:Diagnosis)
return doc,pat,collect(diag)
```

This particular query ignores the direct relationship between `(:Doctor)` and `(:Diagnosis)` but I don't think it's needed for the results you're looking for, since each patient is associated with the diagnoses.